# Sending data to queue not functioning

Tags: java

I have socket connection which keep reading data and then it will send it via a queue for next processing in another thread. I notice at times it just stop sending data to the queue. I will print this System.out.println("\n\nSending TO QUEUE : "+message); and stop but I do not see any error being capture any method to capture the errors? What could also be the possible error here?

```
class ConnectionHandler implements Runnable {

    private Socket receivedSocketConn1;
    ConnectionHandler(Socket receivedSocketConn1) {
      this.receivedSocketConn1=receivedSocketConn1;
    }
    public void run() { 
             BufferedWriter w = null;
             BufferedReader r = null;

              String message="";
              try {

                 PrintStream out = System.out; 
                 BufferedWriter fout = null;
                 w =  new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(receivedSocketConn1.getOutputStream()));
                 r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(receivedSocketConn1.getInputStream()));

                 int m = 0, count=0;
                 int nextChar=0;

                 System.out.println( "\n\n\n THE device"+" "+ receivedSocketConn1.getInetAddress() +":"+receivedSocketConn1.getPort()+" IS CONNECTED ");

                     while ((nextChar=r.read()) != -1) 
                     {                
                          message += (char) nextChar;  
                          int i = message.indexOf("GET");
                                    if(i != -1) { 
                                        break;
                                    }

                          if (nextChar == '#')
                          {
                            w.flush(); 
                                System.out.println("\n\nSending TO QUEUE : "+message);
                                databaseQueue.add(message); 
                                System.out.println("\n\nSent TO QUEUE : "+message); 
                                message="";             
                          }
                     }
                     System.out.println( "\n\n\n THE device close connection"+" "+ receivedSocketConn1.getInetAddress() +":"+receivedSocketConn1.getPort()+" IS CONNECTED ");

                  } 
                  catch (Exception ex)  
                  { 
                       ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
                  }      
                  finally
                  {
                    try 
                    {

                        if ( w != null ) 
                        {
                            w.close();
                        }

                    }
                    catch(IOException ex){
                       ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
                    }

                  }

          }

       }
```

Database processing queue thread snippet code.

```
class DatabaseProcessor implements Runnable {




      // updates databaase with data queued by ConnectionHandler
      Connection dbconn = null;
      Statement stmt = null;
      Statement stmt1 = null;
      Statement stmt2 = null;
      Date connCreated = null;
      public void run()
      {


         // this is just like the QueueProcessor example I gave you
         // open database connection
         createConnection();
             while (true) 
             {

                try 
                {
                    int count=0;
                    String message = "";
                    message = databaseQueue.take();
                    System.out.println("\n\nPICKED AT QUEUE : "+message); 
                    if (message.equals(null)) {
                       System.out.println("QueueProcessor is shutting down");
                    break; // exit while loop, ends run() method
                    }
                     //there is more codes but is too long to be put here.
                     }
                 }
       }
}
```

Comment: What's `databaseQueue`s type? Missing some code

Comment: @peter databaseQueue is another thread maybe I will just a snippet of it in my question too.

Comment: Still no datatype? I assume it's a shared instance between the ConnectionHandler and the DatabaseProcessor.

Comment: @peter the data type is like this private LinkedBlockingQueue<String> databaseQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<String>(); and via the main function I call this new Thread(new DatabaseProcessor()).start();

Answer (score 0):

I edited the code from your example a bit (simplied and removed stuff for testing) and I get the following output:

Client (telnet):

```
telnet localhost 7777
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
peter
test
```

Server:

```
PICKED AT QUEUE : peter


PICKED AT QUEUE : test
```

Code:

```
public class Trash {
    private final static LinkedBlockingQueue<String> databaseQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<String>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new Thread(new DatabaseProcessor()).start();
        try {
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(7777);
            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
            new Thread(new ConnectionHandler(socket)).start();
            Thread.sleep(10000000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    static class ConnectionHandler implements Runnable {

        private Socket receivedSocketConn1;

        ConnectionHandler(Socket receivedSocketConn1) {
            this.receivedSocketConn1 = receivedSocketConn1;
        }

        public void run() {
            try {
                BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(receivedSocketConn1.getInputStream()));
                String message = "";
                while (message == null || !message.equals("") || !message.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")) {
                    message = r.readLine();
                    if (message == null) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    databaseQueue.add(message);
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    static class DatabaseProcessor implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    String message = "";
                    message = databaseQueue.take();
                    System.out.println("\n\nPICKED AT QUEUE : " + message);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```